# chrome command line flag for auto sharing system sound

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

I am developing web automation of Zoom meeting (all the way from creation till joining and leaving thereon).
I have been able to complete the creation, joining and screen sharing automation.
I am using `--auto-select-desktop-capture-source=MyTab` flag to automatically share the desired tab. Up until here, its all working fine.
Where I am stuck is that the chrome tab gets shared without system sound.

[image]

I want to automatically share the screen/tab along with system sound / tab audio.
What is the appropriate chrome flag for sharing audio along with screen?

Comment: Selenium doesn't do audio. You'd need another program to do so.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan, any suggestion for another program?